# XFBML and the Facebook Login button

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Still trying to work Facebook login to my website. I'm trying to add the "Login using Facebook" button that you see on many sites and want to use the methods they outline [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

However, I don't think I'm doing this correctly. At the top of my site, my header reads:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Just like they indicate in the second link I posted.

They say to use the following code to have the Connect using Facebook button (which is shown in the first link (APP_ID is there intentionally... my code DOES use my app ID):

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'APP_ID', 
        cookie:true, 
        status:true, 
        xfbml:true 
     });
  </script>
  <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

But when I use this code on my site the Login with Facebook button is nowhere to be seen. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you put your app's actual `APP_ID` in the `FB.init` call?

Comment: @ceejayoz: Yes, see my comment... I do use my app id.

Comment: Open up firebug console and check if there are any errors printed there.

Comment: @Niklas I have firebug, how do I check for errors on that element?

Comment: @Tony Waterman, if it encountered any problems, they usually are printed onto the console from the FB script. Try adding `FB.api('/me', function(user) {
           if(user != null) {
              alert('working fine');
           }
         });` after your init, and let me know the results.

Comment: @Niklas Here are the errors I get: http://justpaste.it/d0m

Comment: Did you define the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` somewhere in the document?

Comment: @Niklas That was included in the code, they don't tell you anything about what that div is or what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div id="fb-root"></div>` seems to be missing as defined at the [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) you posted