# XFBML and Facebook Login Button

Tags: php, html, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XFBML and the Facebook Login button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364443/xfbml-and-the-facebook-login-button)

I'm trying to add the "Login using Facebook" button that you see on many sites and want to use the methods they outline [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

However, I don't think I'm doing this correctly. At the top of my site, my header reads:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Just like they indicate in the second link I posted.

They say to use the following code to have the Connect using Facebook button (which is shown in the first link (APP_ID is there intentionally... my code DOES use my app ID):

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'APP_ID', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
  </script>
  <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

But when I use this code on my site the Login with Facebook button is nowhere to be seen. 
What am I doing wrong here? I'm fairly sure it isn't quite this simple.

Comment: silly dupe, tip: editing bumps your question

Comment: @Niklas Sorry I didn't tend to my question for every hour of the day yesterday. We all have the end of our work days... I figured that question would be dead by the time I got back. Either way, that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Niklas Now every time I load the page, i get a little popup window that says "working fine". How do I get this to go away??

Comment: @Tory Waterman remove the javascript bit I posted in your previous question.

Comment: @Niklas Got it. Now I'm working towards the end (last code segment of the page) of [this guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) and the code line    <?php } ?> seems to give me errors about an unexpected '}'. This code seems odd.

Comment: @Niklas nevermind, figured out where the bracket was missing.

Comment: Niklas Still trying to figure out the part from the edit in bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you always need to have `<div id="fb-root"></div>` before script loading.